# @CrossOrigin(origins = "*") is not working in firefox

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc

In my controller class I've specified `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")` and I'm trying to connect my angular app but it's not working. I know it's because of Angular is running on 4200 port and Java app is running on 8080 port but is there any way to do it? Without deploying war?

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
public class UserController {
//
}
```

Comment: What did you mean without deployment war? You said its not working on firefox, does this work in other navigator?

Comment: What error do you get in Firefox Web Console ?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using [Spring boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints-cors)

> CORS support is disabled by default and is only enabled once the
>   management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-origins property has been set.

2. Also according to [CORS support in Spring Framework](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework)

> If you are using Spring Security, make sure to enable CORS at Spring
>   Security level as well to allow it to leverage the configuration
>   defined at Spring MVC level.

3. One more problem could be [CORSMIssingAllowCredentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMIssingAllowCredentials)

> If the request is being issued using XMLHttpRequest, make sure you're
>   not setting withCredentials to true.

4. Firefox [Does not support CORS for resources which redirect](https://caniuse.com/#feat=cors)